# convert SELECT query from mySql to Laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel

what would be **Laravel Query Builder** code of this **mysql** query;

```
SELECT * 
FROM Student
WHERE family_id IN (SELECT family_id 
                    FROM students 
                    GROUP BY family_id 
                    HAVING COUNT(1)>1)
ORDER BY family_id
```

Comment: I recommend you to use **Eloquen Models**. Check out the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = DB::select("SELECT * 
FROM Student
WHERE family_id IN (SELECT family_id 
                    FROM students 
                    GROUP BY family_id 
                    HAVING COUNT(1)>1)
ORDER BY family_id")
```

Based on [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#running-queries)

Answer (score 0):

Use function in whereIn clause:

```
Student::whereIn('family_id', function($query) {
   $query->select('family_id')
     ->from(with(new Students)->getTable())
     ->groupBy('family_id')
     ->havingRaw('COUNT(1) > 1')
})->get();
```